# do we say "a box of dental floss"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

do we call it "**a box of dental floss**"?

It could be a round container of dental floss

[image]

or a square container of dental floss

[image]

or it may come in different shapes

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Box" is probably fine.  But "pack" is also possible. If you mean just the coiled up string and not the plastic container then also "spool of floss"